# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of null Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am not too sure where I am going wrong with my form.
So I have this in my html

```
<form [formGroup] = "newEntryForm">
                value: {{newEntryForm.value|json}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-center mb-1 col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Account Infomation
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--Left side-->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">First Name</label>
                                <input formControlName = "Firstname" type="text"  class="form-control" />
                                <div *ngIf="Firstname.invalid && Firstname.dirty"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>First Name Required</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Account Number</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ACC#"
                                    formControlName="AccountNumber" />
                                <div *ngIf="AccountNumber.invalid && (AccountNumber.dirty || AccountNumber.touched)"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Account Number Required</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Right side-->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    formControlName="Lastname" />
                                <div *ngIf="Lastname.invalid && (Lastname.dirty || Lastname.touched)"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Last Name Required</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">ID Number</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="SA ID Number *"
                                    formControlName="IdNumber" />
                                <div *ngIf="IdNumber.invalid && (IdNumber.dirty || IdNumber.touched)"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Valid SA Id required</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center mb-1 col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Contact Infomation
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="row">
                        <!--left-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Mobile</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="072500000"
                                    formControlName="TelMobile" />
                                <div *ngIf="TelMobile.invalid && (TelMobile.dirty || TelMobile.touched)"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Mobile Number is invalid</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4" type="button" (click)="toggleTel()">+ Tel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="addTel" class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Telephone Other</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0"
                                    formControlName="TelOther" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <!--right-->
                        <div class="col-md-6"> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Email Home</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="joe@mail.com"
                                    formControlName="EmailHome" />
                                <div *ngIf="EmailHome.invalid && (EmailHome.dirty || EmailHome.touched)"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Email Format is invalid</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div *ngIf="addTel" class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Telephone Home</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0725000000"
                                    formControlName="TelHome" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div *ngIf="addTel" class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Telephone Work</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0725000000"
                                    formControlName="TelWork" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Address section-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label mb-1">Address Line 1 </label>
                                <input formControlName="Address1Home" type="text" class="form-control"  />
                                <div *ngIf="Address1Home.invalid && Address1Home.dirty"
                                    class="text-danger"><small><strong>Address Required</strong></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Form is longer. My save function calls onSave. my .ts looks like this  :

```
this.newEntryForm = this.fb.group({
      Firstname: ['', Validators.required],
      Lastname: ['', Validators.required],
      AccountNumber: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(25),
      ]],
      IdNumber: ['', [Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('(?<Year>[0-9][0-9])(?<Month>([0][1-9])|([1][0-2]))(?<Day>([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))(?<Gender>[0-9])(?<Series>[0-9]{3})(?<Citizenship>[0-9])(?<Uniform>[0-9])(?<Control>[0-9])'),
      ]],
      Address1Home: ['', Validators.required],
      Address2Home: ['', Validators.required],
      Address3Home: ['', Validators.required],
      PostalCodeHome: ['', Validators.required],
```

my OnSave function:

```
 onSave(){
    console.log(this.newEntryForm.value);
```

I also do have getters for each control in my .ts like this

```
get AccountNumber() {
    return this.newEntryForm.get('AccountNumber');
  }

  get IdNumber() {
    return this.newEntryForm.get('Id');
  }

  get Firstname() {
    return this.newEntryForm.get('Firstname');
  }

  get Lastname() {
    return this.newEntryForm.get('Lastname');
  }

  get EmailHome(){
    return this.newEntryForm.get('EmailHome');
  }
```

However I get a Cannot read property 'invalid' of null error and the form seems to be only keeping track of the Firstname, Lastname, Acc#, and ID but leaves everything else out. The form is a bit longer but I have shortened it for the question.

Any ideas of where I could be going wrong?Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use `?` symbol to check if left side expression is exist or not

```
Firstname?.invalid && Firstname?.dirty
```

It's equivalent to this

```
Firstname && Firstname.invalid && Firstname.dirty
```